# I want to execute BasicExample.java given in http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/software/edison/

Tags: nlp

To execute BasicExample.java we have to add total 18 jar files like edision.jar, curator-client-0.6.jar etc. I have created a batch file and added all jars in it.

On command prompt, first executing the batch file:

```
set classpath=d:\SRL_Demo;d:\SRL_Demo\cogcomp-common-resources-1.2.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\commons-codec-1.8.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\coreUtilities-0.1.7.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\curator-interfaces-0.7.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\edison-0.4.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\gson-2.2.4.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\httpclient-4.1.2.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\httpcore-4.1.3.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\jwnl-1.4_rc3.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\LBJ2Library.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\libthrift-0.8.0.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\snowball-1.0.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;d:\SRL_Demo\curator-client-0.6.jar;

D:\SRL_demo> javac BasicExample.java
   Note: BasicExample.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

D:\SRL_demo> java BasicExample
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BasicExample (wrong name: edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/edison/examples/BasicExample)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:472)
```

Comment: How are you running this example? Are you adding all the dependencies to the classpath?

Comment: Yes, please give the command you are using. It is very hard to help or debug when we don't know the process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download everything from here: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/software/edison/edison-0.4.tar.gz

And add the dependencies into your project. Then you should be able to run the first example.

Update: have a look here: https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/illinois-cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/edison